# Azure Data Factory error connecting to Oracle ADW using Wallet

Tags: oracle, odbc, azure-data-factory

I am configuring an **Azure Data Factory** Self-Hosted Integration Runtime to read data from **Oracle Cloud ADW using a Wallet**. I have installed the SHIR on a VM and extracted the wallet zip file in a local directory in the VM (C:\Oracle).

I followed what is described in the following [resource](https://manavpurohit1.medium.com/azure-data-lake-to-oracle-autonomous-data-warehouse-2a53cb5f723b) but I am still unable to test the connection successfully. I get the following error:

ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]ORA-12203: unable to connect to destination

The SHIR version number is **5.35.8686.1** (Data Factory V2)

To verify that the error is not related to networking issues, I downloaded SQL Developer on the VM and set up a new connection using the wallet file being able to connect successfully.

I also tried to find an ODBC driver capable to connect to Oracle ADW in order to use it instead of the driver included in the SHIR as a workaround, but it seems that the Oracle Instant Client ODBC driver is not capable of using a wallet to connect to ADW.

Do anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: For those who are interested, I used the workaround of setting up an ODBC source in the SHIR VM using the Oracle Intant Client 21.12 ODBC Driver. Still not able to use the SHIR integrated Oracle ODBC Driver though.

Comment: V Post your comment as an answer for community help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I used the workaround of setting up an ODBC source in the SHIR VM using the **Oracle Intant Client 21.12 ODBC Driver**. To make it work you nedd also to set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the wallet directory and change the DIRECTORY attribute of the sqlnet.ora file included in the wallet zip, to the wallet directory.

Still not able to use the SHIR integrated Oracle ODBC Driver though.